# Copy and Paste a Table in Jira issue Description?

Tags: jira

Creating a new issue in Jira, I try to copy and paste a table from a previous issue. 
The table appears correctly formatted in the previous issue, and when I click into edit mode, the formatting is as follows

||heading 1||heading 2||heading 3||
|col A1|col A2|col A3|
|col B1|col B2|col B3|
https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=tables

I copy and past this exactly into the new issue, but it doesnt format or look like a table, 
remains in its unformatted state just like above.

Comment: Does the new issue using wiki rendering in the field you are using?

Comment: @mdoar I don't know, how would I check that? And if it's not there, do you know if it can be enabled?

Comment: Take a look at the field configuration being used by the target project for that issue type. Look at the Description and Comments fields' settings for Renderer

Answer (score 6):

Just to be on the safe side, I always wrap table cell contents in a blank space like so:

```
|| heading 1 || heading 2 || heading 3 ||
| col A1 | col A2 | col A3 |
| col B1 | col B2 | col B3 |
```

This seems to work better than without the extra spaces.

Also, @mdoar is correct in suggesting that you look at the Description and Comments field settings for Renderer.